# How do we handle dynamic form scenario in database

Tags: database, forms, dynamic-forms

I'm creating a application where in I have requirement of dynamic forms. Something like shown below (This structure is kind of, where in there can be 'n' number of diseases and 'n' number of symptoms/attributes for each disease.)

Disease 1:

Attribute 1
Attribute 2
Attribute 3

Disease 2:

Attribute 4
Attribute 5
attribute 6

and the list goes on. Basic idea is, I serve forms as per request and all forms can be different. So number of forms here isn't fixed. Now the question arises how to handle it in DB. How will my tables look like?

Will I have different tables for all my forms which tell me the fields in form and storing all form input as blob in DB ?

Is there a architectural approach to achieve this ?

Or is there a altogether diff approach to handle such scenarios ?

Comment: Key/Value pair database design is probably what you're after... But, it also depends on how you want to query this data.

Comment: @Trent  I just modified my ques a bit. I need to query the data to generate the reports. one report will be related to one type of form

Comment: If the structure is completely dynamic, using a noSql database structure like Mongo may be your best bet. Just take the values and push the object graph into the database for each form. However, you will have to write your own reporting implementation if you want to slice and dice your data in ways other than the object graph that you stored. Reporting will be your hard part.

Comment: Thanks @JimWooley, noSQL is a new thing for me. Will check that out